# passing object created within a block to outside world with NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a `NSBlockOperation` which creates some objects. An `NSString` and `NSData` are put in a user info `NSDictionary`. The block then sends a `NSNotification` with such userInfo.

This is a code fragment:

```
    NSArray *dataHolder = // this array is filled with data created within block
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:idKey, notificationDataKey, nil];
    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:identifier, dataHolder, nil];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
    // notification follows
```

There's nothing special with this code, my concern is about the dataHolder, which is just an `NSArray` of `NSData`, in particular this is used to create images on the fly and passed to be used for display (no manipulation), and the block is not using or altering them after notification.

I cannot use delegation, because several controllers may be alive and waiting for that data.

I am asking if this scenario can cause any sort of problem, and if I need to take special care for variables, for example marking them with weak, strong, block, or other.

The whole project is under ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but you should note the following:

- Userinfo is strong-referenced by the notification object
- Your dictionary is strong-referenced by the userInfo object
- As long as you finished your operation in the other thread, and don't modify the data anymore, there is no multithreading problem
- When sending notification, be careful in which thread you receive the data, as this can cause a problem in receiver of notification. In general the old API of NSNofificationCenter receives calls in same thread of sender. New API (block-based) allows you to specify which queue to receive the notification to.